# trouble to create variable in R

Tags: r

I need create a variable called "dollars_per_day=gdp/population/365 "in R use packages"dalabs". (remember to remove any rows with missing data). Then Construct a boxplot of dollars_per_day (dpd) for the different continents in 1970.

I try summary gap minder, and it show me the data. But when I try to create variable it show me object not found.

```
library(dslabs)
summary(gapminder)
dollars_per_day <- c(gdp/population/365)
```

Please help with what's wrong in my code. And help with the box plot question

Comment: the year 1970 is not in the dataset `unique(gapminder$year)#
 [1] 1952 1957 1962 1967 1972 1977 1982 1987 1992 1997 2002 2007`

Comment: sorry about that mistake. It's 2000

Comment: 2000 is also not there

Comment: I updated the post about the boxplot part with the 'year' that is found in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

The column names are not correct

```
library(gapminder)
library(dplyr)
gapminder$dollars_per_day  <- with(gapminder, gdpPercap/pop/365)

out <- gapminder %>%
            filter(year == 2000) %>%
            transmute(continent, dollars_per_day = gdpPercap/pop/365)  %>%
            {split(.$dollars_per_day, .$continent)}

out %>% 
     boxplot
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got this question